After restarting Ubuntu, it fails to run gdm
I restarted my Ubuntu system computer, and now it fails to go into gdm:
Failed to start gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager


Is this the whole story? Your system was running perfectly every day until today? No chronic error messages? Admin(s) made no recent mistakes with commands? No recent experiments? If not, then review your syslog, journal, and apt logs for unobserved changes.

Try editing /etc/gdm3/custom.conf and uncommenting #WaylandEnable=false (the 7th line of custom.conf) to WaylandEnable=false to disable Wayland.
If that doesn't work switch the display manager from gdm3 to lightdm. As its name suggests lightdm is a more lightweight login display manager than gdm3. Switching from gdm3 to lightdm will still allow you to login to the GNOME desktop environment as usual.
sudo apt install lightdm  
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm   
sudo reboot 

sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm will open up a new window allowing you to select lightdm as the default login display manager. Use the arrow keys to select lightdm, press the Tab key to put the focus on <OK> and press Enter. Then reboot by running sudo reboot
